# Unable to retrieve the method of fstream object

Tags: c++, oop

I have two source codes. First code uses `iostream`, second code uses `fstream`, but the second code has the following error:
[image: Error]

This is the first source code

```
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class Reactangle
{
protected:
    float a, b;
public:
    virtual void input(istream& inDevice)
    {
        cout << "Nhap chieu dai: ";
        inDevice >> a;
        cout << "Nhap chieu rong: ";
        inDevice >> b;
    }
};
class Square : public Reactangle
{
public:
    void input(istream& inDevice)
    {
        cout << "Nhap canh";
        inDevice >> a >> b;
    }
};
void main()
{
    Square *Test = new Square;
    Test->input(cin);
    system("pause");
}
```

This is the second source code (it errors)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
#pragma once
class CCatalogue
{
protected:
    string m_ID;
    string m_Title;
    string m_Author;
    int m_Count;
public:
    /*int input(fstream f, int Pos) 
    {
        f.open("Input.txt", ios::in);
        f.seekg(Pos);

        f >> *this;
    }*/
    friend fstream& operator>>(fstream& f, CCatalogue &List);

};
fstream& operator>>(fstream& f, CCatalogue &List)
{

        //Read ID
    f >> List.m_ID;
        //Read title
    getline(f, List.m_Title);
        //Read author
    getline(f, List.m_Author);
        //Read amount of borrow
    f >> List.m_Count;

        return f;
}
class CBook : public CCatalogue
{
private:
    string m_Publisher;
    int m_Version;
    string m_Year;
public:
    int input(fstream f, int Pos)
    {
        f.open("Input.txt", ios::in);
        f.seekg(Pos);
        f >> *this;
    }
    friend fstream& operator>>(fstream& f, CBook &Book);
};

fstream& operator>>(fstream& f, CBook &Book)
{


        //Read ID
    f >> Book.m_ID;
        //Read title
    getline(f, Book.m_Title);
        //Read author
    getline(f, Book.m_Author);
        //Read amount of borrow
    f >> Book.m_Count;
        //Read the publisher
        getline(f, Book.m_Publisher);
        //Read the version
        f >> Book.m_Version;
        //Read the year
        getline(f, Book.m_Year);
    return f;
}
int main()
{
    fstream f;
    int Pos=0;
    CBook *Temp = new CBook();
    Temp->input(f, Pos);
}
```

Comment: Take a closer look at the `CBook::input` function, especially it's arguments.

Comment: ^this. And on a sidenote, do not use *new* unless you really have to, which you clearly don't here. Just use e.g. `Square test; test.input( std::cin );`

Comment: What on earth is the meaning of your title?

Answer (score 0):

The `basic_ios` copy constructor is made private, so that you cannot accidentally copy a stream object. Like passing it by value to a function...

In modern code the copy constructor and assignment operator would likely be deleted (`= delete`), but that option wasn't available in C++98.

Answer (score 0):

For the function `input()` you try to copy the `std::fstream`. Streams cannot be copied (the error message is rather bad, though; hopefully the implementation will get updated and get an `= delete`d copy constructor). You'll need to pass the argument by reference.

Note that even when you get your program to compile, it most likely won't work: when switching between formatted input (i.e. `in >> value`) and unformatted input (e.g. `std::getline(in, value)`) you'll normally need to skip leading whitespace. An easy approach to do so is to use `in >> std::ws`.

It was already pointed out that you should *not* allocate objects using `new` unless you absolutely have to. If you do allocate objects using `new` you'll also *have to* release them appropriately using `delete`.